# Updating a database field in an associated table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

I have a database called "users" which includes a column called 'rating'.

A user can receive 'Awards' from another user (either 1, 5 or 10 value) which is saved in the "Awards" database (:award_name, :award_value, :user) <del>where :user is the id of the user who receives the award.</del> **(check edit)**

What I want to know is, when I am saving the award data to the Awards database, how can I simultaneously update the 'rating' field in the Users database by the value of the award?

So far this is my code for saving the award in the awards_controller. The @points successfully contains the value of the award, I just want to know what to add here to update the User table.

```
def create
  @points = Award::TYPES[params[:award][:name]]
  @award = current_user.awards.build(award_params)
  if @award.save
    flash[:success] = "Award Given!"
    redirect_to recipe_path(params[:recipe_id])
  else
    flash[:danger] = 'You have already awarded this user!'
    redirect_to recipe_path(params[:recipe_id])
  end
end
```

Hope that makes sense. Thank you!

**EDIT: Changed Question**

I attempted to simplify my situation but I think I have gotten off on the wrong foot.

Users can *award* **RECIPES** created by other users. When an award is given to a recipe (selecting either 1, 5 or 10 points) the Awards database is populated with :name, :user_id, :recipe_id, :points (where the user_id is the id of the user who GAVE the award).

Awarding the recipe is working perfectly, I just need to transfer the number of points the award holds to the rating of the user who owns the recipe.

I have 2 questions. Do I need to create another column in the award database for the id of the recipe owner (i.e. the award receiver) and then everytime I load a user to count the sum of the points from the awards they have received **OR** is there a way of updating the users rating as soon as the award is saved?

Comment: I have 1 question. Is rating and award_value same??

Answer (score 2):

Since `user` has_many awards, you can simply do:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
...
  def rating
    recipies.joins(:awards).sum(:award_value)
  end
end
```

There is no need to update anything on the model, it will react automatically when new award is added to user.

Comment: Thanks for this. Im just a little confused how to call this after `if @award.save`. Do I add anything to the awards controller?

Comment: You don't need to. Every time you call rating on any instance of the user, it will get all user's awards and sum up its values.

Comment: I tried to simplify my question but I think it backfired. I have edited it to show it in more detail. I hope it makes sense!?

Answer (score 0):

You have your user object with `current_user`. You could create an instance method on `User` that will update the points value.

```
class User
  def reward_points(points)
    self.rating += points
    self.save
  end
end
```

So in your `create` action, if the award saves then call `current_user.reward_points(@points)`, you probably don't even want `@points` to be an instance variable, instead just do `points` and pass that to the method.

Comment: Also as a cleanup, you probably don't want to redirect if the `@award.save` fails. Instead you should `render :new`

Comment: This might be quite dangerous - it will save all attributes which has been changed on given instance and it might fail if any validation didn't pass.

Comment: You can make your approach safer using update_column - it saves only specified attribute and skips validation.